# react-native-appearance make a gradle error

Tags: react-native

Hey i have a error with gradle on my react native app (when i run yarn android)

```
yarn run v1.22.17
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 980 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 32 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\project react native\appfirst\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\build.gradle' line: 23

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-appearance'.
> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-appearance'.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\project react native\appfirst\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\build.gradle' line: 23

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-appearance'.
> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-appearance'.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

    at makeError (C:\Users\roro3\Documents\project react native\appfirst\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\roro3\Documents\project react native\appfirst\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\roro3\Documents\project react native\appfirst\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\roro3\Documents\project react native\appfirst\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I see a error with react-native-appearance but i don't understand why.

I got this error after instalation of some package (react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view)

Answer (score 1):

`react-native-appearance` is deprecated and you no longer have to use it. If you are on gradle 7+, you probably are on a newer version of react-native and you can use the [Appearance](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appearance) module.

Answer (score 0):

I also got into some problems with the react-native-appearence package. If you use expo you shouldn't have this problem or just update the package to version `0.3.4`.
If you use use the react-native-cli the only option for you is to downgrade your react-native to a version which is using Gradle 6. You can find more information [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/12774) about this issue.